# How to deploy Vaadin 22 to Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

I downloaded a Vaadin22 starter-app using [this](https://start.vaadin.com/app) link. Everything works fine using the embedded Server.

But deploying to Tomcat 8.5.35 raises the following error in localhost.log (I tried also with V14 and V23, same issue):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application Lookup instance is not found in the interface com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinContext instance. It means that the container has not executed Lookup initialization code: so either the container is not Servlet 3.0 compatible or project configuration is broken.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.lambda$get$0(ApplicationConfiguration.java:58)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:73)
```

As a result the servlet is undeployed.

To deploy to production I switched to **war**-packaging in pom.xml and executed the build with *mvn clean package -Pproduction*. Afterwards I copied the .war-File manually to the Webapps-Location.

The error message mentions Servlet 3.0 compatibility. But [this Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) clearly states that Tomcat 8.5 supports [Servlet 3.1](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you write your own code, or did you try deploying the starter app directly unmodified?

Comment: Perhaps you should mention any settings you changed from default in that starter-app builder tool.

Comment: Is your Tomcat server running on the same Java version as your Vaadin app target?

Comment: Thanks guys. Java-Version is 17 for both Tomcat and app-Target. No change in the generated code.

Comment: Show exactly how you changed the POM.

Comment: The website you mentioned generates a Spring Boot based starter. If you want a Jakarta EE based starter, you need to do all changes manually or you can download a starter package here: https://vaadin.com/hello-world-starters There you can find a servlet based Vaadin starter with Vaadin 21. Have you tried that? It is very easy to update from v21 to v22 for a hello world project.

Comment: The same issue here